# Converting flash project to flex project

Tags: ios, flash, apache-flex

I want to convert a flash file (*.swf) to a flex project so that I can able to run it on iOS devices. Any suggestions how to run a *.swf file on Iphone/ipad/ipod?

Answer (score 2):

Flash Professional can package mobile applications, as well Flash Builder can also package pure ActionScript projects.  There is no need for Flex.

Otherwise, you can simply package your SWF with the ADT command line packager:

**Download Adobe AIR SDK**
http://www.adobe.com/products/air/sdk/

**Install**
Unzip and save to:

C:\SDKs\AIR

Add path:

C:\SDKs\AIR\bin

Java path must be defined, or use from Flash Builder JRE

C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4\jre\bin

**Package**

```
adt -package -target [ipa-test | ipa-debug | ipa-app-store | ipa-ad-hoc]
    -keystore iosPrivateKey.p12 -storetype pkcs12 -storepass qwerty12
    -provisioning-profile ios.mobileprovision
    HelloWorld.ipa
    HelloWorld-app.xml
    HelloWorld.swf icons Default.png
```